# How to get clicked cell column in DevExpress XtraGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I can't get column name of clicked cell in GridControl of XtraGrid. How can I do that? I'm handling `GridView.Click` event.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Within the click event you can resolve the clicked cell as follows:

```
void gridView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Point clickPoint = gridControl.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    var hitInfo = gridView.CalcHitInfo(clickPoint);
    if(hitInfo.InRowCell) {
        int rowHandle = hitInfo.RowHandle;
        GridColumn column = hitInfo.Column;
    }
}
```

However, I suggest you handle the GridView.MouseDown event as follows (because the GridView.Click event does not occur if clicking a grid cell activates a column editor):

```
gridView.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(gridView_MouseDown);
//...
void gridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    var hitInfo = gridView.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);
    if(hitInfo.InRowCell) {
        int rowHandle = hitInfo.RowHandle;
        GridColumn column = hitInfo.Column;
    }
}
```

Related link: [Hit Information Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument770)

Comment: How can I do this in devexpress mvc?